# Import models.py from parent directory

Tags: python, django

Why is it so hard to import a module from a parent directory in python.
I have this file "upload.py" in my app directory

```
import os
import sys
from books.models import Books
print(Books.objects.all())
```

This is my app directory format

```
- books
  __init__.py
  models.py
     -uploader
      __init__.py
      upload.py
```

So I am trying to import the model into the upload file ad it is logging

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'books'
```

[image]

Comment: You can (and should) use relative imports. `from ..models import Books`.

Comment: now it says `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Then you have an issue that is likely explaining the original error: are you sure you have the proper directory structure of `__init__.py` and importing from the package root? Your project seems to think that `uploader` is not a subpackage of books.

Comment: The directory structure is as I indicated i the question. Thank You

Comment: take a picture to your directory because I have made a replicate of your issue then I got the right output as I expect from ..models import Books

Comment: @NSJCorps Are you running upload.py as a standalone file? Because that would also cause the issue.

Comment: I have added the screenchot

Comment: @NSJCorps How are you running `upload_pdf.py`. It should not be run as a standalone script, and rather the functions called as part of the greater package. Also, you can do `from books.models import Books` or `from ..models import Books`, but you cannot do `from models import Books`.

Comment: I was running it as standalone, I tried all those imports by the way. So how am I to run it? I want to run just that file

Comment: @NSJCorps That is your issue then, glad to find out. You should either create a scripts folder that then imports the `books` package. Relative imports or module imports don't work for standalone scripts, it should be run as a package.

Comment: I really dont understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198393/discussion-between-alexander-huszagh-and-nsj-corps).